# How to detect objects in video with darknet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yolo

I am using darknet to detect objects in image, and it is very helpful. Further more, I also want to detect objects from a video in my computer.

I installed Open CV and my computer does not have GPU. I think that I should change something in my darknet.py file. But what code should I add more? Could you give me a clear instruction? Thank in advance.

Comment: That's a totally new operation and if it is provided by darknet then it would be covered by their documentation.

Comment: I tried to find the answers on github :(

Comment: A late answer maybe, but as Alex Weavers mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52564664/how-to-detect-objects-in-video-with-darknet#comment92068049_52564664), it was a total new operation. Now it is mentioned in the documentation. If you are using [yolo darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) you can use the 'demo' option directly in the command line as mentioned by Alexey [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-use-on-the-command-line).

Answer (score 1):

If you looked at the `darknet.py` file carefully, you will find an example on how to extract objects from a given image. Did you try it? If you did not I recommend you to try it first before moving into videos.

Then you will need to move into videos. [Here is a link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) to `OpenCV` documentation, that they explain how to read video files and streams. From this code you will be able to extract frames of the video.

Then you can use the code in `darkent.py` and feed the frames to it.

If not there are darkent wrappers that can be useful. 
[Here is a link](https://github.com/Ramesh-X/pyyolo) to one. There is a documentation that you can read and install it in your machine. It is very easy to use. It already has a example on how to use it on images. You can modify it and work with videos.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pyyolo

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')
meta_filepath = "/home/rameshpr/Downloads/darknet_google_server/data/obj.data"
cfg_filepath = "/home/rameshpr/Downloads/darknet_google_server/cfg/yolo-lb.cfg"
weights_filepath = "/home/rameshpr/Downloads/darknet_google_server/backup/yolo-v3.weights"


meta = pyyolo.load_meta(meta_filepath)
net = pyyolo.load_net(cfg_filepath, weights_filepath, False)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    yolo_img = pyyolo.array_to_image(frame)
    res = pyyolo.detect(net, meta, yolo_img)

    for r in res:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, r.bbox.get_point(pyyolo.BBox.Location.TOP_LEFT, is_int=True),
                      r.bbox.get_point(pyyolo.BBox.Location.BOTTOM_RIGHT, is_int=True), (0, 255, 0), 2)


    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Try the above code after you finished installing `pyyolo`.